NetBSD driver: flags always true for memory pages
I am trying to write a driver for NetBSD that will reserve 10 pages of virtual memory, then provide the first 5 pages with physical addresses. At the end, I output the page number, its physical address, and flags such as Valid, User and Modified. However, it seems to me that the flags are not working correctly, since for all pages, all flags have the same value, which is 1 (true). Please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong.
#include <sys/cdefs.h>
#include <sys/module.h>
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>
#include <uvm/uvm.h>

MODULE(MODULE_CLASS_MISC, driver, NULL);
#define PAGESIZE 0x1000
extern paddr_t avail_end;
vaddr_t va;
struct pglist plist;
static int lab4_modcmd(modcmd_t cmd, void* arg) {
   va = uvm_km_alloc(kernel_map, PAGESIZE*10, 0, UVM_KMF_VAONLY);
   if (va == 0) {
      return 0;
   }
   int error = uvm_pglistalloc(PAGESIZE*5, 0, avail_end, 0, 0, &plist, 5, 0);
   if (!error) printf ("LAB4 loaded\n");
   struct vm_page *page = TAILQ_FIRST(&plist);
   for(int i = 0; page; i++) {
      pd_entry_t *ppte;
      ppte = L2_BASE+pl2_i(va+PAGESIZE*i);
      paddr_t pa = VM_PAGE_TO_PHYS(page);
      printf("Page - %d\n", i+1);
      printf("Valid - %d\n", ((*ppte & PG_V) ? 1 : 0));
      printf("Used - %d\n", ((*ppte & PG_U) ? 1 : 0));
      printf("Modified - %d\n", ((*ppte & PG_M) ? 1 : 0));
      printf("Physical address - 0x%lx\n", pa);
      printf("\n");
      page = TAILQ_NEXT(page, pageq.queue);
   }
   uvm_pglistfree(&plist);
   uvm_km_free(kernel_map, va, PAGESIZE*10, UVM_KMF_VAONLY);
   return 0;
}

I tried to look for other examples where these flags are used.
